# Trim string field in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a db table with column of datatype char(20). I'm not allowed to change it to a varchar.

I'm writing a JPA entity mapped to this table. I would like the string field representing this column in my entity class to always contain the trimmed value, not the 20-character value padded with spaces that exists in the db.

I can't see any easy way to do this. (an annotation would rock!). At the moment I'm just returning a trimmed value from my getter(), but this feels like a kludge.

A google search is offering no help on this. Any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering, what would happen, if you'd use `@ColumnDefinition` and define the column as `VARCHAR` even though it is a `CHAR`. Most likely the result would be either the same or an error.

Comment: The annotation @ColumnDefinition is only useful when you are generating the db schema. If you do not mind using pure Hibernate and deviating from the JPA standard you can use Hibernate @ColumnTransformer provided that you have a database function to do the work of 

You can find how to do it in the Hibernate reference:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-column-read-and-write

Comment: I do not see what is wrong with your original solution. Your current apprpoach is the correct one. As you can see in the answers suggested, it won't get any simpler than that. The only better solution is: change the database field to VARCHAR, which you said you can't.

Comment: @edalorzo if we're talking about one or two properties, I agree. If this is a pattern that appears all over a large code base, using a dedicated listener is much more reliable

Comment: @sean patrick floyd yep it is appearing all over a large code base.

Comment: I had similar problem composited key(two fields) value has trailing spaces. Could not use @PostLoad function it gave `Attempt to change a primary key field of an instance that already has a final object id.  Only new, unflushed instances whose id you have not retrieved can have their primary keys changed.`.  I settled on using `return id.trim()` in a getter method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Or you can use lifecycle annotations:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @PostLoad
    protected void repair(){
        if(myStringProperty!=null)myStringProperty=myStringProperty.trim();
    }

    private String myStringProperty;
    public String getMyStringProperty() {
        return myStringProperty;
    }
    public void setMyStringProperty(String myStringProperty) {
        this.myStringProperty = myStringProperty;
    }

}
```

If this occurs on multiple entities you can create a custom annotation and write a dedicated EntityListener.

**Annotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Trim {}
```

**Listener**

```
public class TrimListener {

    private final Map<Class<?>, Set<Field>> trimProperties = 
        new HashMap<Class<?>, Set<Field>>();

    @PostLoad
    public void repairAfterLoad(final Object entity) throws Exception {
        for (final Field fieldToTrim : getTrimProperties(entity.getClass())) {
            final String propertyValue = (String) fieldToTrim.get(entity);
            if (propertyValue != null)
                fieldToTrim.set(entity, propertyValue.trim());
        }
    }

    private Set<Field> getTrimProperties(Class<?> entityClass) throws Exception {
        if (Object.class.equals(entityClass))
            return Collections.emptySet();
        Set<Field> propertiesToTrim = trimProperties.get(entityClass);
        if (propertiesToTrim == null) {
            propertiesToTrim = new HashSet<Field>();
            for (final Field field : entityClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (field.getType().equals(String.class)
                    && field.getAnnotation(Trim.class) != null) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    propertiesToTrim.add(field);
                }
            }
            trimProperties.put(entityClass, propertiesToTrim);
        }
        return propertiesToTrim;
    }

}
```

Now annotate all relevant String fields with `@Trim` and register the Listener as default entity listener in your persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit ..>
    <!-- ... -->
    <default-entity-listeners>
      com.somepackage.TrimListener
      and.maybe.SomeOtherListener
    </default-entity-listeners>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: +1 This answer is more relevant. Remind me to learn how to construct Annotation and EntityListener.

Comment: Looks like the best solution, will give it a go. tyvm.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd (+1) Have tried it out, works for the most part, but the last declaration is not right, AFAIK - it is not possible to define an entity listener in the persistence unit declaration. One would need to define the listener in an orm.xml (or similar), like explained [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event).

Comment: or use the @EntityListeners(YourListener.class) annotation on the entities

Comment: @kostja funny, it seems you are right. I took that from the book EJB3 in Action, but I can't find it in any official docs or XSDs

Answer (score 24):

**The accepted answer (using JPA entity listeners / @Trim annotation) is a dangerous one.**  Calling the setter on the retrieved entity appears to mark the entity as dirty.  When I tried this myself at a root entity level (using Spring3 / hibernate), it triggered tons of extraneous updates to related entities that were otherwise not modified during the transaction.  It was a real mess in production, and tracking it down to this being the cause took time.

In the end I opted to go with the more straightforward approach of trimming each of the fields manually on-demand (in a custom entity-to-domain mapper, or in the entity getter) similar to Edwin's answer.

Comment: I'm using `@EntityListeners(YourListener.class)` on my JPA Entity with `@PostLoad` in order to internalize Strings (i.e. `myStringField.set(myEntity, ((String)myStringField.get(myEntity)).intern())`). So my approach is equivalent to Sean Patrick Floyd's solution. But I never seen the "tons of extraneous updates" you mention.

Comment: @JulienKronegg Was your annotated JPA entity related to another (possibly on the 'many' side of a one-to-many relationship)?  Or were you always updating these annotated entities anyway?  The former was my scenario.  So despite my best attempts to configure it otherwise, all annotated child entities were getting updated even though the parent entity was the only one being changed.  The moment I removed the `@Trim` annotation, that behavior ceased.

Comment: I'm using this Listener to internalize Strings on about 300 JPA entities, so of course some of them are on the 'many' side of a one-to-many relationship. But even on such big object graph, I never noticed the "tons of extraneous updates" you mention. Since it wasn't noticed, I never investigated further.

Answer (score 20):

It's an old question but it was very useful for me to get to my answer. In my case, the easiest way was to create a simple "javax.persistence.Converter", like this:

```
@Converter
public class StringTrimConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData.trim();
    }

}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ViewAddress")
public class PostalAddress extends DbObject { 
    @Convert(converter = StringTrimConverter.class)
    private String street;
    @Convert(converter = StringTrimConverter.class)
    private String number;
    (...)
```

It works just fine.

Comment: Simple and easy solution :) Thanks

Comment: Your answer helped me. In addition to that sometimes, if the value from DB is null. We will lead to a null pointer exception during Trim. Below code worked for all times



`return dbData!=null ? dbData.trim() : null;`

Answer (score 4):

I am using this method, which makes the trimming transparent without having to use annotations in every string field.
In the same package that you have your session factory class (the one you use to get Sessions, e.g `org.blablabla.yourpackage.etc.SessionGetter.getSession()`, you must create a file named `package-info.java` and put this content inside it:

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "trimmedStringType",
                defaultForType = String.class,
                typeClass = StringUserType.class)
})
package org.blablabla.yourpackage.etc;

import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;
```

Then you create the class `StringUserType` in this same package:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;
import org.hibernate.usertype.EnhancedUserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class StringUserType implements EnhancedUserType, Serializable {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = new int[]{Types.VARCHAR};

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        if (x == y) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        String dtx = (String) x;
        String dty = (String) y;
        return dtx.equals(dty);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object object) throws HibernateException {
        return object.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Object s = StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names, session, owner);
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return s.toString().trim();
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, null, index, session);
        } else {
            StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, value.toString().trim(), index, session);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) value;
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToSQLString(Object object) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String toXMLString(Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromXMLString(String string) {
        return string;
    }

}
```

And that's it, no need to create custom annotations in your beans, it will "magically" trim the strings whenever you get the objects from the database.

Answer (score 3):

Put the annotation on the getter method, set the @Acesss to AccessType.Property and trim the field there using String.trim() method.

Or simply put the trim in the getter method and always access the field through it. It is not going to get any simpler than that.

If you do not mind using pure Hibernate and deviating from the JPA standard you can use Hibernate @ColumnTransformer provided that you have a database function to do the work of

You can find how to do it in the Hibernate reference:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-column-read-and-write

I hope that helps!

Comment: Yep - this is what I did already. I'm using OpenJPA, which does have a similar feature, but using vendor-specific features is worse for us than using the getter workaround.

Answer (score 2):

What JPA provider are you using?

If you are using EclipseLink CHAR fields are trimmed by default.  You can disable this through the session trimStrings property (ensure you have not set this).

Comment: See my comment below ... I'm using OpenJPA, which does have a similar feature, but using vendor-specific features is worse for us than using the getter workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer works except registering the listener in persistence.xml. I did it with orm.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <entity-listeners>
            <entity-listener class="org.example.TrimListener">
         </entity-listener>
        </entity-listeners>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
  </persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is put this on your controller and it works as expected you dont need a listener or anything of that

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

Comment: Thank this did n't work for me. I used trim instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain requirement states it needs trimmed information, you need to store the data in trimmed value. I see nothing wrong about it.

> **Domain Model**
>   An object model of the
>   domain that incorporates both behavior
>   and data. (PEAA - Martin Fowler)

If you explicitly have to enforce the business rule at the database level, one option is that you have a choice of writing a trigger, you can use built-in SQL trim method. But it will be like using a rocket to crack an egg.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my issue. The values are entered as eg "abc". Because the field is CHAR not VARCHAR, the values are being returned as eg "abc                  ".