# Handle JPA padding

Tags: jpa

I have a property that is persisted through JPA. However if I were to set it to something like "1" then when it is persisted, it looks like "1                          " due to a "getPrecision" (I am assuming here) of 27. So when I go back and try to search for "1" it can't find the item.

I know I could use the setter to add a "minimum" padding but that doesn't seem very clean. Is there something I can do in the annotations so that "1" will be made into "1                          " or vice-versa?

I tried...

```
@Column(precision=27)
```

But that didn't seem to work.

This does seem to work...

```
    private static final int PADDING_COUNT=27;
public void setSerial(String serial) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(serial);
    while(sb.length()<PADDING_COUNT)
        sb.append(" ");
    this.serial = sb.toString();
}
```

but seems rather bulky

Comment: Do you use a varchar(27) for the field or a char?

Comment: Char but I cannot change that.

Comment: precision is invalid for String fields, length would be more appropriate. What type of field is it ?

Comment: String is the type see the above setter

Comment: What about this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725491/trim-string-field-in-jpa

Comment: so if its a String then remove "precision" as I said. The "length" argument is for that when using Strings